# how to pass js variable to hidden value in form with query selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im trying to add the latitude and longitude form javascript to a hidden form value so when i submit it it reverse goeocdes your address  , but am not sure how to achieve this.  can someone pls help  ?

```
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates. Copy paste them in the fields to get your address</p>

</address></p>

<button onclick="logLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
var successCallback = function(data) {
  document.getElementById('de').innerHTML=('latitude: ' + data.coords.latitude + ' longitude: ' + data.coords.longitude);
var lat = data.coords.latitude;
var long = data.coords.longitude;
  var lat= document.getElementById("demo").value
  var long = document.getElementById("lat").value
};

var failureCallback = function() {
    console.log('location failure :(');
};

var logLocation = function() {

    //determine if the handset has client side geo location capabilities
    if(navigator.geolocation){
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, failureCallback);
    }
    else{
       alert("Functionality not available");
    }
};



</script>


<p id="demo"><p/>







  <h4>Enter either address or coordinates</h4>


      <%= form_for @place do |f| %>
    <small class="text-muted">You can also enter IP. Your IP is <%= request.ip %></small>



    <%= hidden_field_tag 'latitude',  {:id =>'lat', value = ''}%>
     <%= hidden_field_tag 'longitude', {:id =>'demo', value = ''}%>

  <%= f.submit 'Add!', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure all you need is to set the `value` of those fields to your latitude/longitude

```
var successCallback = function(data) {
  document.getElementById('de').innerHTML=('latitude: ' + 
  data.coords.latitude + ' longitude: ' + data.coords.longitude);
  var lat = data.coords.latitude;
  var long = data.coords.longitude;
  document.getElementById("demo").value = long;
  document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
};
```